# Can hickeys induce a heart attack / stroke?

Tags: medical-science, cardiology

According to a [lot of sources](https://www.google.nl/search?q=hickey%20heart%20attack&oq=hickey%20heart%20attack&aqs=chrome..69i57.5664j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you could suffer a stroke or heart attack by getting a hickey. However I can't find [any papers](https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?hl=nl&q=hickey%20heart%20attack&btnG=&lr=) on the matter. Since this lead to a heated argument between me and my girlfriend, me using the argument that even a lot of newspapers would publish hoax stories if they sell more copies because of it. So my question is, is it true?

The top 4 google result lead to:

- http://abcnews.go.com/Health/Sex/love-hurts-hickey-leads-stroke-paralysis/story?id=12731131
- http://www.medicaldaily.com/hickey-kills-teenage-boy-blood-clot-stroke-caused-love-bite-girlfriend-396464
- http://www.popsci.com/can-you-really-get-blood-clot-and-die-from-hickey
- http://chloeofthemountain.com/humor/can-a-hickey-kill-you/

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) The trouble with linking to a Google search is we all get different results. The top links on mine all say that hickeys *cannot* cause heart attacks. Can you please link to two or three specific claims?

Comment: I would think that a very young, sexy, attractive lady with very little clothing administering a hickey to my middle-aged person might, indeed, induce a cardiac event.  I'm not sure that it's the hickey, itself, that would be considered the cause, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two cases where hickeys may have caused strokes.

One [in 2010 in New Zealand](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/Sex/love-hurts-hickey-leads-stroke-paralysis/story?id=12731131) and one [in 2016 in Mexico](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/teenager-dies-love-bite-from-girlfriend-causes-stroke-julio-macias-gonzalez-mexico-city-a7215171.html).

The case from 2016 is probably too recent to be mentioned in any papers, but here is the [case report](https://www.nzma.org.nz/journal/read-the-journal/all-issues/2010-2019/2010/vol-123-no-1326/cc-wu) for the 2010 case, published by the New Zealand Medical Association:

> We report on an interesting case of blunt carotid artery trauma caused
>   by a love bite. Blunt carotid artery trauma can lead to arterial
>   injury, thrombosis and cerebral embolisation. It is a rare phenomenon
>   and diagnosis requires a high index of suspicion. Current literature
>   suggests a conservative approach to treatment with anticoagulation.
>   Most patients achieve a favourable outcome especially when initial
>   neurology was non-disabling.

Comment: Yes we refer to the same source, but I'm doubting it's credibilaty. I was looking for scientific papers (studies) not newspapers. So is there any real scientist who would back up these claims?

Comment: @Thomas The new zealand medical journal is peer-reviewed. I doubt you will find more credible sources for a medical issue that appears to only have affect two people.

Comment: So the answer is "Yes,it's possible, but it's incredibly unlikely." [You are more likely to be killed by a falling piano.](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/3101/has-anyone-ever-been-killed-by-a-falling-piano-or-anvil)